# How to install wordpress theme's plug-ins?

Tags: plugins, themes

I need you're help, as I'm sort of a noob at installing extras in themes. I installed the [Metro Magazine](http://themeforest.net/item/metro-magazine-responsive-wordpress-theme/3834138) theme on my wordpress site, but the metro magazine theme has some plug-ins to increase functionality that I can't install in my theme.  When I upload each plug-in in zip or rar format, I get this error:

**Failed to install plug-ins** 
When I try to install this theme completely using the Appearance > Theme as theme installation, with all it's plug-ins in zip or rar format, I can't install this theme so first I installed theme with out the extra plug-ins and it installed with out any Error. Can someone help me find a way to install this theme completely, using it's own plug-ins as a theme installation or how can I install this theme's plug-ins, after I install the theme  without the plugins. : Raha

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are trying to upload archive files to the plugin directory. You can't do that. You need to upload the original source files.

1. Unzip or unrar the plugins
2. (s)FTP the decompressed files to `wp-content/plugins`
3. Activate the plugins from the backend control panel

That should be all you need to do.

Some of the other parts of your question are confusing but whether you can install a theme + plugins in one shot probably depends more on the theme that anything else.

Comment: If you don't like manual uploading, use the Plugins Menu to Upload and Activate each plugin, using the [Plugin Directory](https://wordpress.org/plugins/).  The Plug-Ins should be listed in the Documentation.

Comment: @ECarterYoung : I don't like the manual updating. Honestly, the system is a terrible idea for business applications, which is what I deal with pretty much exclusively.